# Cannot disable single click in elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files, dconf

I cannot disable single click in elementary OS Juno.

I tried `sudo dconf write /org/pantheon/files/preferences/single-click false`
I tried `sudo gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences single-click false`

I also tried dconf editor.But shows no schema available.Changing to false doesn't have any effect. I have attached the screen shot of dconf editor.

Note: I don't want to use elementary-tweak tool

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can control this behavior using *gsettings*. You have edited the correct setting using:

> sudo gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences single-click false

Just a small thing: when you run any command with sudo, you are running it as administrator user, not the user you are logged in and, in your case, the setting is changed for the administrator user, and not the user which runs files applcation.

Simply, run this command without *sudo* and it should work just fine.

> gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences single-click false

Comment: Still the same.Its not working.

Comment: Changing the setting `io.elementary.files.preferences single-click` either from the command-line, as above, or using dconf-editor, works for me using Files version 4.1.8

Answer (score 0):

1. Install and launch [elementary tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks).
2. Go to Files and disable Single Click (see screenshot).[image: elementary tweaks]

Answer (score 0):

With Elementary OS 7 (Horus) the setting seems not to be available in pantheon-tweaks anymore. I found that the gsetting key changed:

```
# Use single click to select only    
gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences singleclick-select true 

# Single click opens folders directly
gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences singleclick-select false
```